# Invariant subspaces for endomorphisms with associated Jordan matrices

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, jordan-normal-form

I would like to know which are the invariant subspaces for the endomorphisms $f1$, $f2$, $f3$, $f4$, $f5$ from vector space $V$ that have the next associated Jordan matrices:

$J1 = \left( \begin{array}{cccc}
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 2 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \end{array} \right)$

$J2 = \left( \begin{array}{cccc}
-1 & 0 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 2 \end{array} \right)$

$J3 = \left( \begin{array}{cccc}
1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 1 \end{array} \right)$

$J4 = \left( \begin{array}{cccc}
-1 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & -1 & 1 & 0\\
0 & 0 & -1 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & -1 \end{array} \right)$

$J5 = \left( \begin{array}{cccc}
3 & 1 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 3 & 0 & 0\\
0 & 0 & 3 & 1\\
0 & 0 & 0 & 3 \end{array} \right)$

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

The space spanned by the generalized eigenvectors associated with each simple Jordan block is invariant with respect to the relevant endomorphism. So that is if you decompose $V$ into a direct sum of the smallest possible invariant spaces (with respect to the relevant endomorphism). Now you also have that each generalized eigenspace associated with a specific eigenvalue is also invariant with respect to the relevant endomorphism.

So let's consider an example - let's take the first endomorphism $f_1$ and its Jordan form $J_1$. Then we can express $V$ as a direct sum of $f_1$-invariant subspaces: \begin{equation} V=V_{-1,1}\oplus V_{-1,2} \oplus V_{2,1}, \end{equation} where $V_{\lambda,i}$ represents the subspace spanned by the generalized eigenvectors of $f_1$ associated with each simple block $J_i(\lambda)$. Now we also have $E_{f_1}(-1)=V_{-1,1}\oplus V_{-1,2}$ is the generalized eigenspace associated with eigenvalue -1, and $E_{f_1}(2)=V_{2,1}$ is the generalized eigenspace associated with eigenvalue 2. So we also have $V$ expressed as a direct sum of $f_1$-invariant subspaces: \begin{equation} V=E_{f_1}(-1) \oplus E_{f_1}(2). \end{equation}

I hope that helps...you should be able to do the others on your own?